# How to automatically deploy node repo on github in linux server?

Tags: github, ssh, continuous-integration, forever, autodeploy

I have a linux server as my a production environment, and my node repo is on github . 
When I push my code, if I want to deploy it , I need to .

```
>local
git push
ssh user@host

>remote
cd repo
git pull
```

I am using node forever to auto update my code , but it is still a very troublesome .

Is there any solution , like [travis-ci](http://travis-ci.org) or [heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) , can Automatically deploy my code on github ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis-ci is for continuous integration (as its name)
While Heroku is just a cloud platform.
They are not for deployment.

My solution is to set up a git hook on your server, push to it to trigger the hook, and do whatever you want in that script.

for example, you can:

1. cd ~/repo && mkdir myproj && cd myproj
2. git init --bare
3. edit ~/repo/myproj/hooks/post-update

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   unset GIT_DIR;
   cd <your project-root>
   export NODE_ENV="product"
   git pull
   npm install
   pm2 restart <your app name>
   ```
4. chmod +x ~/repo/myproj/hooks/post-update

now you can add your repo on server as one of your remotes

There's some services available to monitor your deployment, such as http://dploy.io/ and https://www.codeship.io/

Feel free to use them when your business grows up.

Comment: I use the [dploy](http://dploy.io) to achieve automated deployment, although the server root permissions pay out feeling somewhat insecure .